# spark-scala: Filter RDD if the record of the RDD doesn't exist in another RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD that has the structure as follows:

```
((user_id,item_id,rating))
```

lets call this RDD as training

Then there is another rdd with the same structure:

```
((user_id,item_id,rating))
```

and this rdd as test

I want to make sure data that is in test doesn't appear in train per user basis. So lets say

```
train = {u1,item2: u1,item4 : u1,item3} test={u1,item2:u1, item5}
```

I want to make sure item2 is removed from u1 training data.

so what I started doing is groupBy both rdd(s) (user_id, item_id)

```
 val groupedTrainData = trainData.groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2))
```

But I feel like this is not the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `PairRDDFunctions.subtractByKey`:

```
def cleanTrain(
  train: RDD[((user, item), rating)],
  test: RDD[((user, item), rating)]) =
  train.subtractByKey(test)
```

Comment: does this subtract by a key? assume if I have (user, item, rating, someother information) can I subtract just by (user,item)?

Comment: `PairRDDFunctions` operates on `RDD[(K, V)]`. In my example `K` is `(user, item)`.